# Realm Swift primary key would not retrieve the correct value

Tags: swift, realm

I am trying to retrieve the properties for a given object in my Realm Database. Every property is showing up correctly except the Primary Key, which always has its default value.

For example:

**A.swift**

```
    @objcMembers class A: Object, Codable{
        var id: Int64 = 0
        dynamic var otherProperty: String?

        private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case id
            case otherProperty
        }

        override static func primaryKey() -> String{
            return "id"
        }
    }
```

Let's say we have class *A*, as shown in the above example. When I am adding the A object into the Realm Database, with a given *id=10* and *otherProperty="other property"*, it saved correctly. I can even see it with Realm Browser.

Now, I'm trying to use the following code:

```
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let aObj = realm.objects(A.self).first
    print(aObj!.id) //printing 0
    print(aObj!.otherProperty) //printing "other property"
```

The problem here, obviously, is that I do not receive in *aObj*, the value of *id=10*, as I would expect.

I have tried debugging it to see what the problem was, and the strangest thing happens there. `po aObj` would print my object correctly:

```
    Optional<A>
       some: A{
          id = 10;
          otherProperty="other property"
    }
```

However, if I try to print out only the id, so if I run the `po aObj!.id` command, I get the following result:

```
    Optional<Int64>
      - some : 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your id dynamic

```
dynamic var id: Int64 = 0

realm.add(A(value: ["id": 10, "otherProperty": "otherProperty"]) , update: true)

print("aObj?.id") //printing 10
```